# Changing Views with MGSplitView Controller

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

In the app that io am creating, i have a custom copy of UISplitView Controller, MGSplitViewController. I have implemented it into my project which started off with the MultipleDetailViews sample code from apple.

I have come across a problem where i cant seem to switch between viewcontrollers. When i push the tableview cells, the detailview controller should change according the the nib assigned, however that doesn't happen.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

/*
 Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
 */
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

UIViewController *detailViewController = nil;


if (row == 0) {
    FirstDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

if (row == 1) {
    SecondDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailView" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
}

// Update the split view controller's view controllers array.
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[viewControllers release];

[detailViewController release];
```

Normally this code would be enough to change the views in the original Multiple Detail View code.

has anyone run into a similar problem? any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just creating new view controllers. You're not adding them anywhere. You add view controllers to the split view controller by using its `viewControllers` property.

**EDIT:** I've used `MGSplitViewController`, but I never tried to change the detail view like that. I just pushed the new detail view controller onto the navigation controller. Is there a specific reason for wanting to change the detail view controller entirely?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, could you elaborate a little on that answer. I have this code below what i showed you:   


    NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    [viewControllers release];

Comment: @user You should edit your question to include that. That's probably the most relevant part.

Comment: @user, Your code looks like it should work. I updated my answer to suggest a different approach.

Comment: What i had done previously with the multiple detail view sample code is i had detached nib files that represented separate pages, so that when i pushed one of the cells in the table view, the detail view controller would change its appearance according to the nib file associated with it. i am trying to do the exact same thing here, but so far it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: the difference is that i would like the functionality of the mgsplitviewcontroller